# Cannot receive echo replies from others

Tags: python, icmp

Only "destination unreachable" replies are received while using given snippet(handler is pyicmp.handler.Handler from https://github.com/volftomas/pyicmp):

```
def IPScanner(handler, ip, file, lock):
    for ttl in (32,):
    # putting 32 in a tuple was necessary here, 
    # otherwise do_ping() acts as a noop
        ctr = 0
        for j in range(0,4):
            t = PrintThread(str("Dest:" + ip + " TTL" + str(ttl)), lock)
            t.start()
            ping_result = handler.do_ping(ip, ttl)
            if ping_result['packet_loss'] == 0:
                ping_result['packet_loss'] = j
                break
        else:
            ping_result['packet_loss'] = 0
        d = DumpFileThread(file, ping_result, lock)
        d.start()
```

Some hosts send destination unreachable and others block echo request, I cannot share dumpfile because dumpfile I have now has IP mappings of a corporate institution. I can ping the IPs passed to this function via Windows's `ping`. Why can I not receive pings from pyicmp library. ICMP echo is not blocked on my host.

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: If you try this code pinging localhost (127.0.0.1) does it work?

Comment: Pinging localhost with or without loopback works.

Comment: There could be a firewall/router blocking the ICMP packets.